# R paste formula for gamm

Tags: r, paste, mgcv

I am trying to programmatically create the formula for a `gamm` estimation, which I want to use later in a Shiny app. My goal is to create a formula of this kind:

```
y ~ s(x, bs = "cs")
```

Im stuck because I dont know how to paste the part after the comma: `bs="cs"`.

```
input<-list()
input$x<-"mpg"
input$y<- "hp"

 formula<-as.formula(paste(input$y_variable," ~ ",paste(paste("s(",paste(input$x_variable,collapse="+")),', bs="cs")')))
 
z <- mgcv::gamm(formula, data=mtcars)
```

Comment: Instead of `input$y_variable` use `input$y`. And the same for `input$x`. The output now becomes what you want, `hp ~ s(mpg, bs = "cs")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cases where multiple commands entered in a single line start messing with your understanding of the code, it usually makes sense to break them up:

```
dep_vars    <- paste0(input$x, collapse = "+")
after_tilde <- paste0("s(", dep_vars, ", bs = 'cs')")
dyn_string  <- paste0(input$y, " ~ ", after_tilde)

mgcv::gamm(as.formula(dyn_string), data=mtcars)
```

However, it turns out that the actual problem is that you defined `input$x` and `input$y`, but you were using `input$x_variable` and `input_y_variable` in the formula creation instead

Answer (score 0):

I generally advise against going the character route for this. Usually it's better to compute on the language:

```
input <- lapply(input, as.name)
z <- eval(substitute(mgcv::gamm(y ~ s(x, bs = "cs"), data=mtcars), input))
```

This substitutes `x` and `y` in the expression with the names from `input` and evaluates the expression.

Comment: input<-list()
     input$y_variable<-"wt"
     input$x_variable<-"mpg"
     input<-c(input$y_variable,input$x_variable)
     input <- lapply(input, as.name)
     z <- eval(substitute(mgcv::gamm(y ~ s(x, bs = "cs"), data=mtcars), input)) . I tried this but it did only gave me an Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'y' not found

Comment: Well, `eval(substitute(mgcv::gamm(y_variable ~ s(x_variable, bs = "cs"), data=mtcars), input))` in that case. Obviously.

Comment: Thanks. I see that the point was obvious. What is a bit less obvious is how would I tackle this if input$x_variable and input$y_variable are reactive values in a shiny app. It would be great if you could add a comment about this case.